# What is the cost of require() in node.js?

Tags: unit-testing, node.js, requirejs, require, mocha.js

I have a test suite using `mocha.js` that I run to ensure that everything works as it should. For every module I require, I notice about 100ms increase in testing time. And that's on a powerful quad-core machine with 8GB of memory.

What is the real cost of calling `require` and does it affect application performance or only testing performance?

Version of node is `0.8.11` if that's relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Require is quite costly as it is not executed during any static analysis. It needs to do several things, which it does **synchronously**, blocking your program for undefined period of time:

- It needs to find the module you are requiring which can result in lots of file operations - including path searches, stat, open.
- It needs to read the javascript file, parse it, compile parts of it and during execution **require** any dependencies it encounters - so again first point.

You shouldn't use `require` in any non-top level code, require everything before your tests unless you are prepared to pay the price of increased execution time.

There used to be an asynchronous version of `require` in very old Node.JS, unfortunately it seems not anymore.

Comment: Note, though, that once a module has been `require`'d, it's cached and a subsequent call to `require()` for the same module will be very quick, as it doesn't have to load or compile again.